# (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'usuario_id'") en django

Tags: python, mysql, base-de-datos, django, django-models

estoy terminando un proyecto con django y mysql donde cree un usuario personalizado usando abstractbaseuser

aqui el model

```
class Usuario(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True,)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', unique=False, max_length=250)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD='username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=[]

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

ahora, tambien cree un modelo perfil para a la hora de la hora junto con @receiver se cree el perfil junto al usuario

```
class Perfil(models.Model):
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(Usuario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Usuario)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Perfil.objects.create(usuario=instance)
    
    
@receiver(post_save, sender=Usuario)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.perfil.save()

@receiver(post_save, sender=Usuario)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """
    Signals the Profile about User creation.
    """
    if created:
        Perfil.objects.create(usuario=instance)
    instance.perfil.save()
```

el problema aquí es que luego de que pasa todo esto quise probar crear un nuevo superusuario y me da el error en el titulo, si alguien pudiera ayudarme se  lo agradecería

**actualizacion**

este es el traceback

```
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\gastos\users\views.py", line 24, in sing_up
    form.save()
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 143, in save
    user.save()
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 68, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 812, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 863, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1006, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1047, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1790, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1660, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 103, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "c:\proyectos\first-proyect\venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'")
[15/Dec/2022 11:20:55] "POST /register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 185952
```

tambien agregare como luce la tabla en la base de datos
**esta es la tabla de usuarios:**

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| password     | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_login   | datetime(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| usuario_id   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username     | varchar(250) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| email        | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_staff     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_superuser | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


**y esta la tabla perfil:**
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| usuario_id | int(11)    | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

si me pudieran ayudar a entender por qué ocurre el error que aparece en el titulo y como solucionarlo lo agradeceria

Comment: Es importante que pongas todo el stacktrace del error, no solo la última línea con el mensaje.

Comment: @KevinRamirezZavalza ya lo agregue, tambien las tablas de base de datos

Comment: podrías mostrar como tienes el UserManager, por favor puede que la raíz del problema esté por ahí